# How to rename multiple files based on a dictionary in Python?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, rename

My files look like this:

```
file_name_unique_123.pdf
file_name_unique_456.pdf
file_name_unique_789.pdf
```

I created a dictionary based on a csv file that has multiple columns and one is containing the unique IDs of the files like '**unique_123**' etc:

```
list = csv.DictReader(open('file.csv'), delimiter = ';')
for row in list:
    print(row)
```

Now I have the dict:

```
{'ID': 'unique_123', 'name': 'one', 'time': '1',}
{'ID': 'unique_123', 'name': 'two', 'time': '2',}
{'ID': 'unique_123', 'name': 'three', 'time': '3',}
```

I managed to get the IDs of the files and list them by doing this:

```
file_IDs = fnmatch.filter(os.listdir(folder), '*unique*.pdf')
[i.split('.', maxsplit = 1)[0].split('_', maxsplit = 5)[5] for i in file_IDs]
```

so I now have this output:

```
['unique_123',
 'unique_456',
 'unique_789']
```

What I need to do somehow is matching the IDs in the file names with the dictionary IDs and rename the files based on the columns that belong to that record.
Example:
**file_name_unique_123.pdf** should be renamed to **one_1.pdf** based on the first record in the dictionary.

How do I do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the filename always in fomat `file_name_unique_xxx.pdf`?

Comment: Yes, they are always in that format.

Comment: Then loop through your list of ids and call os.replace("file_name_"+id+".pdf", dst]

Comment: Yeah I know, but I don't know how exactly. I don't understand how to get the right data out of the dict. Could you provide a little code to help me get started, please?

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
for row in list:
    old_name = "file_name_{}.pdf".format(row['ID'])
    new_name = "{}_{}.pdf".format(row['name'], row['time'])
    os.rename(old_name, new_name)
```

Another approach: if there are redundant records

```
import pandas as pd
import re
df = (pd.DataFrame(csv.DictReader(open('file.csv'), delimiter = ';'))
      .set_index(['ID']))
files = fnmatch.filter(os.listdir(folder), '*unique*.pdf')
for file in files:
    unique_id = re.search(r'.*_(unique_[0-9]+).pdf', file).group(1)
    new_name = "{}_{}.pdf".format(df.loc[unique_id, 'name'], 
                                 df.loc[unique_id, 'time'])
    os.rename(file, new_name)
```

Comment: Thank you. What if the csv contains two lines with the same IDs and I want to skip the second line?

Comment: And the other problem with this is that it goes based on the dictionary so that if there is a record in it which doesn't exist as a file, an error occurs. I need to loop the files instead because there are less files than records.

Comment: @Pepszi I have updated the answer. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't. A "KeyError: 'ID'" happens in the line starting with "new_name" because I wanted "ID" where you typed "name". I have been trying to solve it by using "name" instead as you did and then the last line caused "The system cannot find the path specified:" error and a lot of file names listed after it. I think that's beacuse without using ID in the file name some files would be named the same. Any idea?

Comment: @Pepszi I can't help you much. You will have to check if we do not use `ID` then multiple files will be renamed to same file or not? If you want to use `ID` in place of `name` then I can update the answer.

Comment: Also `uniqueID` is repeated in your dict which shouldn't be the case.